# I can't see the content because of the FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the layout I have. There's no error or something else. The textView after the frame layout cannot be displayed. If I remove the frame layout, all the next elements are displayed

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.andre.nutridian.Home"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="359dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="MENIU"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
                
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_accessibility_black_24dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Banking"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Raport"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/dieta"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_pie_chart_outlined_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Ideas"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Diete"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/calcul"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_today_black_24dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Add"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Liste alimente calorii"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/statistici"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundyello"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_trending_up_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Ideas"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Statistici"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have done everything in the same way as in the tutorial I have used. I don't know what to do and I would appreciate some guidance or advice if you know the problem. Thank you

Comment: Question is very unclear. You are using drawerLayout so there must be FrameLayout as a container. What you want to achieve?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit I found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing your FrameLayout to wrap_content instead of match_parent in android:layout_width and android:layout_height in your xml file and it will work :)

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>
```